# How can I make an image slider for any number of images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following code, but it only works for lots of images, what if I have 1 image, 2 images, 10 images, or even 100 images, how can the CSS adjust for that? (PS, I am using ReactJS/NextJS/TailwindCSS , but if the answer works with HTML and CSS, I can make it work with ReactJS/NextJS/TailwindCSS)

Main File

```
[1,2].map((e,i)=>{
                    return(
                        <div key={i} className="w-[250px] slide flex align-center p-[15px]">
                            <img src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2560px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"} alt={"sht"} />
                        </div>);
                })}
```

CSS File:

```
.slider{
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width:100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px*18); /*image width * total number of slides including dublicates   */
    animation: scroll 10s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes scroll{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px*9)) /*-250 move left by half the width*/
    }
}
```

Comment: _I have the following code, but it only works for lots of images_ What do you mean by "works"? Are you getting an error somewhere? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Works meaning, that it appears as the images are alway going, if there not enough images the images appear to start in the middle of the screen instead of the right-end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using reactjs, you can use the [react slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) package. Map through the array of images like you normally do and then the package will take care of all the styling, adjustments to mobile screens, also gives you complete control on CSS as well.